# Authorize.net Automatic Recurring Billing (ARB) has stopped working

Tags: civimember, joomla, authorize.net

We have been running with Authorize.net for long while now. This past January I setup ARB for membership renewals, and it was working great. We have numerous ARB subscriptions since then. Then, 2 weeks ago, they stopped working.

The membership transaction processes in Authorize.net, but it does not create the ARB subscription. Also, the contribution in CiviCRM stays at Pending, and never is moved to Completed.

The setup in Authorize.net hasn't changed. The Silent Post URL is set properly. Other non-ARB transactions are working properly.

I am at a loss as to what has happened to cause this to stop working. Does anyone have any thoughts on this? Any ideas would be appreciated.

CiviCRM 4.7.8, Joomla 3.5.1

Answer (score 2):

All the payment processors have been tightening up security, especially with regards integrations between systems.

My first inclination would be to check if the SSL postback that Authorize.net uses has the correct secure protocols set up.  Specifically, you should be sure that your server is configured to accept TLS 1.2 connections. Check with your hosting provider if necessary.

If this fails to help, I would recommend that you reach out to Authorize.net to see what information that may have in their logs with regards to the failure.